# How to remove an empty line left behind by an <xsl: /> tag from transformed file from .xsl file

Tags: vb.net, xslt, transformation, removing-whitespace

I am using an .xsl file to generate a .vb file and am using multiple if, choose, etc xsl tags in it.

But what is happening is the xsl tags are leaving behind blank lines after transformation in the result and this is not desired. How do I remove them?

Refer below .xsl file code -

```
 Dim Result as String = ""
    <xsl:for-each select="/xyz/Process">
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
          Select Case processId</xsl:if>
```

So, here the result .vb file has an empty line in between.

```
Dim Result as String = ""
    
          Select Case processId
```

Tried adding xsl:strip-space in the beginning and that did not work out for me.
Also tried adding <xsl:output method="text"/>

Comment: Did you try `<xsl:text>Select Case processId</xsl:text>` ?

Comment: The XSLT instructions don't generate the white space, it is your deliberate use of white space in your text nodes in XSLT instructions and between. As @SiebeJongebloed has already pointed out, to control white space with text generation, use `xsl:text` explicitly instead of just formatting your text and between XSLT instructions.

Comment: Hi guys, I had to use `<xsl:text></xsl:text>` to solve this issue. Had to use it a number of times as XSL doesn't allow you to control anything inside the text tag.

Comment: It appears that the code generator was giving white lines in the generated code where the generator skipped some code for the conditional statements.